# OpenKm 6.3.0 is not starting in Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, server, openkm

Previously I used OpenKM 5.1.11 But now I want to install OpenKM 6.3.0.

I just unzip openkm-6.3.0-community-tomcat-bundle.zip. in /opt
I tried sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run I got error.

So please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://www.filetolink.com/ee9115cd29 - error log is attached in the link.

Answer (score 1):

There are few other configuration that you need to do which I believe is not mentioned in their documentation.

1. **OpenKM.cfg** has to be updated
   hibernate.hbm2ddl=create
   for the first time until there are no issues in server startup.
2. **context.xml** 
   Uncomment the Resource tag for hsqldb(A file based repository, which comes default with OpenKM)
3. There are few other jar files which I believe is not present in tomcat lib folder which is required for OpenKM
   spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, mail-1.4.7.jar, log4j-initializer.jar, log4j-1.2.17.jar, jta-1.1.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, hsqldb.jar
   If the above jars are already present then skip step#3